# 'spinnaker-igor' was not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

For the first time, I am installing Spinnaker on AWS. I am following spinnaker documentations.

https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/aws/

But when I am running "hal deploy apply" command it gives an error.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Version '0.7.0-20171002182452' for 'spinnaker-igor' was not found
! ERROR Error encountered running script. See above output for more
  details.

I checked the install.sh in /home/ubuntu/.hal/default directory and I see it has configured with Spinnaker repository.

Repo is "https://dl.bintray.com/spinnaker-releases/debians". I check that repo and I could find a correct version of spinnaker-igor.

Could you please give an idea to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's possible that bintray was being flaky. The exact package you were trying to download exists [here](https://bintray.com/spinnaker-releases/debians/spinnaker-igor/0.7.0-20171002182452) and has been published since Oct 2. You can retry `hal deploy apply` and if fails again let us know.